# tensorflow keras training GAN stops after roughly 200 images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

i'm using tensorflow 2.2.0 and keras to train a GAN to predict an image sequence. to do this i created a custom model by subclassing the keras `Model` class and implementing `train_step()`. it works just fine, but for some reason, always, at around 208 images each time it's training, it just freezes. it doesn't exit or give any error, but it just freezes and i can no longer interrupt it with the keyboard, i have to exit the terminal completely. my code basically looks like this:

```
    checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint \
    (
        filepath = os.path.join(util.get_dir("save/checkpoints"), "checkpt"),
        save_weights_only = True,
        save_freq = 25
    );

    image_save = callbacks.ImageSave(util.get_dir("save/images"));

    model = models.GAN(num_scales = 4, hist_len = 4, pred_len = 1);
    model.compile \
    (
        disc_optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-6, beta_1 = 0.89, beta_2 = 0.99),
        gen_optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-4, beta_1 = 0.89, beta_2 = 0.99),
        disc_loss = losses.Adversarial(),
        gen_loss = losses.Combined(),
        metrics = [ metrics.PSNR(), metrics.SharpDiff() ],
        run_eagerly = True
    );

    model.fit \
    (
        dataset,
        epochs = epochs,
        callbacks = [ checkpoint, image_save ]
    );
```

i'm using a `tf.data.Dataset` to handle the input pipeline. all the outputs and everything work just fine until image 208, regardless of how i split up the batches.

Comment: Did you tried with a dummy dataset, such as using random numbers as images? Just to check if it is the input or not. And the losses are ok? Since you changing the batches, it can be related to something that the code does at the image "200", maybe the `ImageSave` callback. But is difficult to tell without other parts of the code, maybe you could share a minimal example to reproduce this?

Comment: it works with the dummy dataset, but not with the normal one. the callbacks work fine. i'll edit the post to show what the dataset looks like.

Comment: @K.Bogdan i fixed the issue - i was using `PIL.Image.open` to load my image files from animated PNGs, which would not load the files correctly all the time. i switched to using `np.savez_compressed` and `np.load` to handle the saving and loading